Stochastic calculus in Lean4?
Has anyone started looking into this? Measures and Probability theory look like a good place to start, but maybe there are other resources?
https://leanprover-community.github.io/undergrad.html

Since I’m not an expert on this exact topic, and since the answer is bound to change over time let’s go through the process so that you or others can follow it in the future to answer questions like this.
How to know what is covered about (mathematical topic) in Lean’s Mathlib?
The process I use is as follows:
Check the mathLib overview and undergrad todo lists
For a general list of what topics are covered in MathLib, see the mathlib overview.  If we look at the Probability Theory section, we see the following topics for Stochastic Processes:

martingale
optional stopping theorem
stopping time
hitting time

So Mathlib is making some progress, but there is nothing mentioned about, say, Brownian Motion or the Itô integral.
You can also check the undergrad todo list.  It's undergrad mathematics, so it won't mention Stochastic calculus, but it says Mathlib is still missing Levy's theorem, the weak law of large numbers, and the central limit theorem.
Check the Lean search engines: leansearch.net, Moogle.ai, and search-mathlib
Next, let’s check the search engines for Lean and Mathlib.  We again can find topics like martingale, filtration, and other stuff associated with discrete time stochastic processes, but not “stochastic calculus”, “Brownian motion”, or “Itô integral”.  For stuff like this with canonical names, if the search engines can't find it, it is likely not there.
Browse the Mathlib documentation
With the stuff you can find on the search engines, you can follow the links to the Mathlib documentation.  In particular, you can see that the relevant paths are:

Mathlib.Probability.Martingale
Mathlib.Probability.Process

with lots of files under each.  Also, looking at the definition of Martingale, it is general enough to support any preorder for the time index.
Search on Lean Zulip chat
It is still possible someone is actively working on this topic in another repository.  The best place to find out is the Lean Zulip chat.  Searching for say "Brownian motion" or "Stochastic Calculus" brings up a number of conversations:

https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/113489-new-members/topic/stochastic.20process
https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/217875-Is-there-code-for-X.3F/topic/Should.20there.20be.20a.20ProbabilitySpace.20class.3F

In the first conversation, the expert Jason K.Y. says how a new user can jump in, namely working on defining topics like previsibility, cadlag, and other tools needed for continuous stochastic processes.  He also says they don't have the Gaussian distribution yet, but searching it seems that may have since been added.
Ask on Lean Zulip Chat
Finally, it wouldn't hurt to bring up the topic again on Zulip.  You could find a relevant thread above and follow up by saying:

@username, has there been any progress on this?  I'd love to contribute.

Or you can post a new thread on the streams #new members or #Is there code for X?.  Introduce yourself, explain what you are looking for, and specify how you would like to contribute (if at all).
